# How can I add a new column and check constraint to an existing table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

How can I add a new column to an existing table along with a check constraint on that column?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it all with a single `Alter` statement, using below template:

```
Alter table table_name
add column_name column_datatype
constraint constraint_name check (column_name>some_value)
```

---

example:

```
create table tbl(a int)
go
alter table tbl
add clmn int
constraint constraint_name check (clmn >10);
```